# Recommendation for a Linux distro that I can install on a USB drive

Tags: linux, boot, usb

I have a netbook (no CD drive) that no longer boots. Before I do a factory reset (which is what the manufacturer is telling me I need to do), I want to try and recover my personal data.

So I'm looking for a Linux distro that I can install on a USB drive to boot from. Ideally something super-simple to set up :)

Thanks

Richard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create an ubuntu usb stick, but any distribution will do fine.

Comment: I've used both Damn Small Linux (DSL) and PuppyLinux on USB before to good effect.  Both are good, and small.  unetbootin appears to support the creation of either (as well as Ubuntu, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What immediately comes to mind is DSL or Damn Small Linux. Site is [here](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/).

However, this is not the only option. Depending on the size of USB drive available to you, you might be able to fit just about any distro on the drive.